# Need help with a sentence in my book

Tags: writing

So I'm an aspiring author and I can't wrap my head around how to write multiple peoples names in one sentence but I wrote it as...

"...while I went over Kyle, Jenny, and Marcos’s homework they were supposed to do yesterday."

Like did I write it out correctly? I am genuinely confused.

Comment: What exactly are you doubting?

Comment: "...while I went over the homework Kyle, Jenny and Marco were supposed to do yesterday," perhaps.

Comment: To show separate ownership ( ... authorship, etc) you need to apostrophise each noun. << Jack's and Jill's boats >> means Jack's boat (or boats) and Jill's boat/s. Separate ownership. But << Jack and Jill's boat/s >> is the device used to show joint ownership, here one or more boats co-owned by Jack and Jill.